# The app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error") doesn't catch app exception in .net core razor app

Tags: exception, middleware

I have intranet.net core razor app with default exception handling setting as follows:
app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error") under production evviroment

I have one custom middleware to deal with Windows Authentication with Identity membership and check the user id application user. If not the application user, app throws one exception by
throw new System.InvalidOperationException($"user not found.");

In production, the app never catches the exception instead of 500 error. How to solve this issue? Thanks!

expect to get solution for the issue.